# Prevent IIS from using SSL certificate for other localhost website

Tags: ssl, iis

I'm trying to set up a different website on IIS but it keeps wanting to use an SSL certifcate that is configured for a different website within the same IIS.

**e.g. https://localhost:443 has a security certificate but i want to create http://localhost:98/**

Steps I've done:

1. Created a new application pool
2. Created the website within IIS
3. Edited bindings to point to a specific IP address and port: e.g: http://123.456.789.10:98/
4. Edited binding for localhost to use a different port: 98 e.g: localhost:98/

What's happening is that now whenever I go to localhost:98 or the ip address, it keeps redirecting the site back to the website that has the SSL certificate for it

**eg. I click localhost:98/ but it redirects to https://localhost/**

What can possibly be incorrect with this setup? I had it working before but then when i tried to apply a different SSL certificate, it didn't work, i re-set up everything and it's constantly pointing to this situation.

Comment: Learn some background information and you will see easily what goes wrong, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: Hi @LexLi I'm not able to install that application on the server, unfortunately

Comment: You just need the knowledge and then netsh command is enough to reveal the certificate mappings. You don't really need Jexus Manager.